# Database query using Linq to Sql in an Asp.Net MVC 4 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I'd like some tips on executing some basic table queries into a Sql Server DB using Linq To Sql.

My project is in ASP.NET MVC 4 with c# (using VS2012), but I don't want to write a lot of models and generate entity framework diagrams. I'd like to write manual queries in my controllers, execute them, then convert to a list and return back to my view (i.e. jQuery will parse results and display accordingly).

#### Background

XML Scenario:
My current website project is mostly centered around an XML Request/Response infrastructure. So I'm mostly JQuery calls in c#, and in turn making xml requests into another app server. I then received the xml response and return it to a View. I then parse the xml out and display the contents using jQuery, Datatables, etc.

Database query scenario:
One of the QA tools I wrote is actually a Sql Server Procedure based project; however I'm now trying to write a front-end admin tool to execute those QA-based procedures.

So...I'd like to write manual Linq queries directly to my DB and work on the response without generating models. i.e. more of an ad-hoc type query.

In my web.config I have a `<connectionStrings>` section :

```
<add name="RegrDBConnection" connectionString="Server=MSSQLSERVER2008;Initial Catalog=RegressionResults;Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be in the market for a Micro-ORM.  Sam Saffron wrote one for Stack Overflow; it's called [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/).  Rob Conery also wrote one that takes advantage of the `dynamic` keyword in C# 4.0, called [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive#readme).

Or, you can just go commando and use [SQLConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) and [SQLCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) objects.